# Observing ambiguity in runtime.onStartup and runtime.onSuspend

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background-process, alarm

I'm writing a Chrome extension that is supposed to fire alarms at regular intervals. On an overview it works correctly, but there are some corner cases that I'd want to address.

The requirement is, after the browser is opened, start firing alarms at the specified intervals, once the browser is closed, clear all the alarms. Or, alternatively, start firing the alarms once the OS is booted, continue firing alarms at specified intervals, and clear the alarms on shutdown.

Let's assume we're not disabling the `Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed` option.

To achieve the above requirements, I'm using `chrome.runtime.onStartup` and `chrome.runtime.onSuspend` APIs, expecting them to invoke the callback when the browser is opened and closed respectively.
However, from my observation, I could notice that their behavior is ambiguous and non-consistent.
I could sometimes notice `onStartup` getting triggered as soon as the system is booted without having to explicitly open the browser, whereas, at other times, `onStartup` wouldn't run until a browser window was opened. And, a similar pattern was observed with `onSuspend`. After these observations, I'm assuming this has mostly got to do with how & when the OS creates, terminates processes, and manages memory which is something that cannot be directly summoned from the extension's background script, given that `Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed` is enabled.

I was wondering if it is possible to create, fire, and clear chrome alarms at different events (opening/closing the browser) following a consistent pattern? Thank you.

EDIT:
`onStartup`.

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
  console.log("Fired on startup", new Date());
  createOrUpdateAlarms();
});
```

`onSuspend`

```
chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(() => {
  chrome.alarms.clearAll();
});
```

And, `createOrUpdateAlarms`

```
function createOrUpdateAlarms() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(["timeout", "water", "walk"], (items) => {
    const { timeout, water, walk } = items;

    chrome.alarms.clearAll();

    if (timeout) {
      chrome.alarms.create(Alarms.ScreenBreak, {
        delayInMinutes: timeout,
        periodInMinutes: timeout,
      });
    }

    if (water) {
      chrome.alarms.create(Alarms.Water, {
        delayInMinutes: water,
        periodInMinutes: water,
      });
    }

    if (walk) {
      chrome.alarms.create(Alarms.Walk, {
        delayInMinutes: walk,
        periodInMinutes: walk,
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I re-verified the behavior and now I'm able to see onStartup firing precisely when the browser is opened. However, there are issues dealing with async calls in onStartup. Let's say an alarm fires every 10 minutes starting at Xth minute. Now I close the browser at X+5 th minute and wait for 10 minutes, and no alarm is fired at X+10 th minute which is the expected behavior. But when I reopen the browser at X+15th minute, the alarm is fired immediately instead of firing at X+25th minute, but technically I'm clearing the old alarms and creating a new set of alarms in `onStartup`. I'm assuming that the alarms are fired even immediately before they're cleared asynchronously which is what is causing the problem. Ideally, it'd have been great to clear off alarms at `onSuspend` but that's not working either.

Comment: 1) onStartup should fire consistently, otherwise it's a bug or maybe Chrome ignores it if you have several browser profiles and the last one was without this extension. 2) onSuspend is unreliable with asynchronous calls such as chrome API by design, and I don't think you need it because it runs when the event page script is terminated, not the browser session, which you seem to have incorrectly assumed, AFAICT.

Comment: Right, I re-verified the behavior and now I'm able to see `onStartup` firing precisely when the browser is opened. However, there are issues dealing with async calls in `onStartup`. Let's say an alarm fires every 10 mins starting at Xth minute. Now I close the browser at X+5 th minute and wait for 10 minutes, and no alarm is fired at X+10 th minute which is the expected behavior. But when I reopen the browser at X+15th minute, the alarm is fired immediately, but technically I'm clearing the old alarms and creating a new set of alarms in `onStartup`. Any workaround for this? @wOxxOm

Comment: I've updated the question with more information and a few code snippets. Could you kindly check? @wOxxOm

Comment: So apparently a missed alarm is fired intentionally right away. I guess you can check the current `Date` and compare to the alarm's `scheduledTime`...

Comment: How do I determine the `scheduledTime`?  These are recurring alarms that buzz at regular intervals so there's no `scheduledTime` calculated at any point. However, for this use case, it is necessary to make the check before firing it. 
Another approach I could think of is, store some flag when the browser is closed synchronously (like using `localStorage`) and then make a check on this flag before firing the alarm. But, I came to realization that background scripts do not have access to `localStorage` and `chrome.storage.set` is async

Comment: You can use a global variable to let the other listener (onAlarm) know that onStartup has already completed, it can be a mutex or a Promise. You can also delay processing inside onAlarm via setTimeout to make sure onStartup has completed. Just get the time from chrome.storage.local each time the alarm fires, analyze the delta, store the new value.

Comment: Amazing! That works as expected. Thank you. Would you mind writing an answer below? It'd help others facing the same issue.

Comment: I think it'd be better if you post your actual new code.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm I've published my extension [on the web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/take-a-break/oifmahnepecgegpdiomjikkmfmnlbdjo) The initial release worked just fine, and I had to make some changes and when I submitted the updated version for review, it was rejected saying I shouldn't use the "tabs" permission as nothing conforming to the features enabled by the permission was used. After removing the permission and publishing, I'm noticing a strange behavior. It is working correctly on my device but not on few other devices. The alarms are not getting fired as intended.

Comment: However, if I run the unpacked version on any device, it is working just fine. I'm noticing this issue on installing the extension from the web store. I'm unable to figure out the root cause for this. Would you please help me troubleshoot this issue? Here's the [source code](https://github.com/prajwalkulkarni/take-a-break). Looking forward to your response.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong. It may be a bug in Chrome, they still haven't fixed problems with the service worker randomly losing the will to wake up for events, especially alarms.

Comment: It is working correctly on my device, but not on other devices having the exact same version of Chrome as mine. But again, if I run the unpacked version locally on the other device, it is working correctly, how is that possible? The main business logic of my extension relies on alarms, it'd be quite unfair to have such a critical bug from Chrome's end that's left hanging. Is there any way I can contact them or implement a duct-tape solution for the time being?

Comment: That is what bugs are. In this case no one knows how to reproduce it reliably. The bug tracker is https://crbug.com. The workaround is to use chrome.runtime.sendMessage in the popup (e.g. at opening) and if there's no response call chrome.runtime.reload()

Comment: So the thing is, when I try reproducing things locally, it works just fine. The `.onMessage` is invoked correctly on clicking "submit" in the popup. But things are going south in the published version. I've now added `reload` if there's no response. I'll let you know if it works. Thanks a lot for your prompt response.

Comment: Hey, I'm using a callback in the `sendMessage` API, if the response is falsy, I'm running `chrome.runtime.reload()`, like 
`chrome.runtime.sendMessage({...args}, (response) => {if (!response) { chrome.runtime.reload();}});`, but I'm still observing incorrect behavior, In addition, I've also added `reload` if alarm creation fails. Could you kindly confirm if I've implemented it correctly?

Comment: As another workaround, I've created a watchdog alarm that fires every 30 seconds(least possible interval), that way I believe, the server worker never sleeps due to inactivity. Is this approach feasible given that reload is not working fully correctly? @wOxxOm